# PyWinAuto says Computer Management has no windows?

Tags: pywinauto

I'm attempting to change some settings that are accessible via:

Start > Right Click Computer > Manage

The process that is launched by clicking on that switch is called mmc.exe, so I started with this code:

```
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application()
>>> app.start_('mmc')
```

So far, so good - that opens the application for me.

Now I need to do File > Open... so that I can actually open the right settings file. Just one problem:

```
>>> app.windows_()
[]
```

Um... what? Why does it say that this program has no windows? How can I access the window?

Comment: Could you provide more details about pywinauto version python version you use ? I suppose it is on 64-bit version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It works on Win7 x64 with 64-bit Python:

```
>>> app = pywinauto.Application().Start('mmc.exe')
>>> app.Windows_()
[<pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper object at 0x00000000031A9A90>,
 <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x00000000031A9AC8>,
 <pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper object at 0x000000000350E6D8>,
 <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x000000000350E5F8>,
 <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x000000000350E5C0>]
```

Please use appropriate 64-bit Python version for your 64-bit Windows. I see the same empty list in 32-bit Python.